# opencv: matrix assignment confusion

Tags: c++, opencv, matrix, assignment-operator

Could anyone verify/answer my understandings/questions?

In OpenCV, suppose

```
Mat A; // Suppose A has some values in it
Mat B=A;
```

1. If I update B, A is also affected. right? It seems basically assigning by reference.

Suppose a function "void a_function(Mat argument) {..//change argument..}".

2. After you call "a_function(A)", A is also affected, right?
3. Then, why (or in which case) do we need "void a_function(Mat &argument)" if it is already calling by reference? Can `&` have a special meaning here?
4. If you don't want A to be affected by the function call, which one is better habit?

   - calling by `a_function(A.clone())`?
   - calling by `a_function(A)` and declaring the function using `const Mat &argument` and leaving the responsibility to the function?

Suppose you need to calculate row-wise cross product like

```
L.row(i) = A.row(i).cross(B.row(i));
```

5. In this case, the reason that I can safely use this assignment without 'clone()' is that the intermediate result matrix (from `cross` function) will be gone/disappear(?) soon (when exiting the current local scope), right?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> **1.** Yes.

Proof:

```
cv::Mat A = (cv::Mat_<double>(2,2) << 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0);
std::cout << "Original A:\n" << A << std::endl;

cv::Mat B = A;
B.at<double>(0, 1) = 2.5;
std::cout << "A:\n" << A << std::endl;
std::cout << "B:\n" << B << std::endl;
```

> **2.** Yes.

Proof:

```
void a_function(cv::Mat C)
{
    C.at<double>(1, 0) = 3.5;
}

cv::Mat A = (cv::Mat_<double>(2,2) << 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0);
std::cout << "Original A:\n" << A << std::endl;
a_function(A);
std::cout << "A:\n" << A << std::endl;
```

> **3.** When a `Mat` is specified as a function parameter **with or without** the reference `&`, the class uses *smart pointers* internally to point to the original data instead of copying it.

Proof:

```
void some_function(cv::Mat C)
{
    C.at<double>(1, 0) = 3.5;
}

void another_function(cv::Mat& C)
{
    C.at<double>(1, 0) = 3.6;
}

cv::Mat A = (cv::Mat_<double>(2,2) << 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0);
std::cout << "Original A:\n" << A << std::endl;
a_function(A);
std::cout << "A:\n" << A << std::endl;

cv::Mat B = (cv::Mat_<double>(2,2) << 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0);
std::cout << "Original B:\n" << B << std::endl;
a_function(B);
std::cout << "B:\n" << B << std::endl;
```

Since the use of `&` in this case doesn't make a difference, as you pointed out, I do believe using **it improves readability**: people that are not aware of the internal workings of a `Mat` might fear that a copy is being made if the parameter is specified without `&`.

> **4.** It's a matter of taste. I prefer `const Mat& img` because  I think its cleaner and more obvious to C/C++ programmers.

And to answer the last question:

> **5.** Yes.

Proof:

```
cv::Mat L = (cv::Mat_<double>(1,3) << 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
cv::Mat E = (cv::Mat_<double>(1,3) << 1.0, 2.0, 3.0);
cv::Mat F = (cv::Mat_<double>(1,3) << 4.0, 5.0, 6.0);
L = E.row(0).cross(F.row(0));

std::cout << "E:\n" << E << std::endl;
std::cout << "F:\n" << F << std::endl;
std::cout << "L:\n" << L << std::endl;
```

Comment: Your particular question appears to have a few answers already. Just use the search box on the page. Here is a possible answer: https://stackoverflow.com/q/63930667/176769

Comment: Thanks, that the question I asked.