# How to swap rows of Mat in opencv?

Tags: c++, opencv

I want to swap two rows in a `Mat M`, and I have two minor problems:

1. To swap two rows I will need a `MatrixRow temp`(pseudo code) to backup the first row to be replaced. But I don't know what should be the type of a row of a `Mat`.

---

```
Mat temp = img.row(i).clone();
img.row(i) = img.row(j).clone();
img.row(j) = temp.clone();
```

This code doesn't change the img, why?

Comment: What is i and j here ? Are they in a loop ?

Comment: @YunusTemurlenk: Yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
img.row(i) = img.row(j).clone();
```

and

```
img.row(j) = temp.clone();
```

do not copy the cloned data because they invoke the following assignment operator

```
Mat& cv::Mat::operator= (const Mat& m)
```

See the [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#aed1f81fe7efaacc2bd95149cdfa34302)

> Matrix assignment is an O(1) operation. This means that no data is
> copied but the data is shared and the reference counter, if any, is
> incremented.

To do the copying, there's [another assignment operator](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#a2a0798475170fb3a23b5bc63686de334) that you can use:

```
Mat& cv::Mat::operator= (const MatExpr& expr)
```

See [matrix expressions](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d1/d10/classcv_1_1MatExpr.html#details) for details.

So, you can do something like the following to actually copy the data.

```
img.row(i) = img.row(j).clone() + 0;
img.row(j) = temp.clone() + 0;
```

And, you don't need clone. So it can be written as

```
img.row(i) = img.row(j) + 0;
img.row(j) = temp + 0;
```

Here, `img.row(j) + 0` creates a matrix expression, so you invoke the `Mat& cv::Mat::operator= (const MatExpr& expr)` assignment operator in `img.row(i) = img.row(j) + 0;`.

And the other option is to copy the data as the other answer says. You can use `Mat::copyTo` for this.

For further details, see the note in the [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#a4b22e1c23af7a7f2eef8fa478cfa7434) for

```
Mat cv::Mat::row(int y) const
```

It explains this with examples.

Comment: Before you wrote the answer I actually found that `img.row(j).copyTo(img.row(i))` works, and I read from their tutorial that concludes like your first quote: only the header is copied. The `+ 0` technique is a new idea to me, if you could elaborate more on it I will appreciate your work. In short, you solved my problem, thank you!

Comment: I'm learning OpenCV this semester, you might follow my id to answer my problem(s) and I will always vote you if all your answer is such high quality.

Comment: @Raining `img.row(j) + 0` creates a matrix expression, so you invoke the `Mat& cv::Mat::operator= (const MatExpr& expr)` assignment operator in `img.row(i) = img.row(j) + 0;`.

Comment: I would recommend you update your answer, or, (if I have free time) I will help you edit your answer by appending what I think helpful to me to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using clone, I would recommend you to use the following steps:

1. Create a temporary mat of the size of 1 row x n columns, where n is the width of image
2. Copy the pixel values from ith row to temporary mat with the help of for loop
3. Copy the pixel values from jth row to ith row using the same for loop technique
4. Copy the pixel values from temporary mat to jth row

This is a solution based on what I understood from the information provided.

Comment: But I want the code, sorry this doesn't help actually... Still thanks for your time.